# MYSQL, how to search keyword in multiple columns?

Tags: php, mysql, search, syntax

How can I search a keyword in multiple columns in mysql syntax?

Now I have a variable `$phone`, that store the form input, and use the syntax to search in a single column:

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE 'phone1' = '".$phone."';
```

How I make that search through columns 'phone1', 'phone2', 'phone3' and 'phone4'?

Thanks

Comment: I trust that you have sanitized `$phone` accordingly, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `OR` in your `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM db.table 
WHERE 'phone1' = '".$phone."'
OR 'phone2' = '".$phone."'
OR 'phone3' = '".$phone."'
OR 'phone4' = '".$phone."'
```

Comment: But @WilliamdeCastro beware if `$phone` contains the string `"' OR 1=1 --"`

Comment: Yes, they don't show enough code to say whether or not they were sanitizing and/or escaping their data so I didn't elaborate on it.

Comment: @lc $pohne will ever have a simple numeric string

Comment: @WilliamdeCastro How do you guarantee that?

Comment: @BenM it'll be used in a intranet, so who will oparate know that will use only numbers, anyway, I put a JS code that let input numbers only.

Comment: I'm sorry, you simply cannot rely on JS alone to sanitize your DB strings. And, as for running on intranet, never underestimate your users...

Comment: I'll accept the tips, will put any str relpace to sanitize de string. The code work from @JohnConde work anyway. Thanks for all replies. Will accept the answer ASAP;

Comment: Seriously, take that chip off your shoulder. It wasn't a comma, it was a misplaced single quote. The difference? John's answer works, yours didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try `in`: =)

```
SELECT * 
FROM db.table 
WHERE '".$phone."' in (`phone1`, `phone3`, `phone3`, `phone4`)
;
```

Comment: Not sure how logical it is in terms of performance.. tested table:(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/615bf/1) Please leave a comment for the downvotes as `or` is same as `in` and `explain plan shows the same`

Comment: It is, but you should use backflicks instead of single quotes for field names, and you have a mismatch in your quotes anyway.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect and will not work in its current form, hence the downvote.

Comment: That's all you needed to do. There was no need to get childish about it now, was there? ;-)

Comment: Why not then downvote the above answer for the same? if you are downvoting it has to be consistent on your reasoning for all. Isn't it?

Comment: I have already explained why your answer didn't work (you had `'phone4)'`).

Comment: It's not explaining! If everyone here is going to downvote for a typo that could be shown with courtesy, then speechless...!

Comment: No one likes down votes. I wish it were required that down voters had to comment. At least @BenM did.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary likewise.. However mostly users do point out to others with a correct answer instead of downvoting. Those who get 10-15 or more votes for answers we have shown if there're typos/fixes, so correct answer becomes perfect, acceptable worthy. More choices the better. Many users usually upvote or support instead of boggling eyes to just throw a downvote..for a correct logic with tiny typo. If an answer is  unacceptable then by all means it should be flagged with a comment. Oh well **Let bygones...be bygones** I'll still upvote, show anyone if they have a typo given logic is correct:)